# How could Stark's item be used more times than the previous version?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, iron-man, avengers-endgame

In the ending scene of *Avengers: Endgame* movie, Iron Man created his own

> Infinity Gauntlet. First Hulk snapped it to undo the decimation by Thanos in *Avengers: Infinity War*, after that Iron Man used it to kill all the enemies.

How come the material used in Iron Man's

> Infinity Gauntlet could survive two snaps and the massive power of all six Infinity Stones? We do know that Thanos' gauntlet was made of material similar to Mjölnir and Stormbreaker.

How could Stark's item be used more times than the previous version?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

## It Didn't

The first snap was used by Smart Hulk with the Stark Infinity Gauntlet which brought everyone back. However, the second snap was done by Tony using a gauntlet integrated into his suit after he stole the Infinity Stones from Thanos who had them in the Stark Infinity Gauntlet.

One could argue that the Stark Infinity Gauntlet was used twice when Thanos snapped wearing it. Of course though there were no Infinity Stones in it when he did so doing so would be rather pointless.

## And It Wasn't

Thanos' Infinity Gauntlet was actually used twice: once for the snap, and then again three weeks later to destroy the Infinity Stones by Thanos again on Titan II. And Stark's Infinity Gauntlet was only used once as established above.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. New question arises. If a ordinaly earth metal or metal alloy in Stark's infinity gauntlet could be used for all 6 infinity stones then why did Thanos went to Nidavellir to make a guantlet with Uru metal. I mean Thanos could have just made a guantlet locally and house all Infinity stones to it. Please explain how come Stark's gauntlet even survived the snap, when Humans can even weild one infinity stone? Thanks for reading my comment though.

Comment: @MusafirMrinalSamant: Thanos went to Nidavellir to make a gauntlet, period. No-one in Endgame or Infinity War ever confirmed what material the Infinity Gauntlet is made of, nor whether its material was particularly important to its function. As Thor explains in this first movie, magic and sufficiently-advanced technology are indistinguishable. Tony has studied two Infinity Stones at length in *Avengers* and *Age of Ultron*. He figured out how to make an Iron Man-style gauntlet that could wield them. He also invented a time machine during one all-nighter a day or two previously. He's smart!

Comment: Iron man builted 2 Infinity gauntlet, the one used by Mr.Hulk, and the second was integrated to his suit, Stark always have a  plan B

Comment: Also the 2nd snap by Thanos was to destroy the stones. This act seems to have been harder and more devastating then any other act with the stones.

Comment: I think the only purpose-built Iron Gauntlet was the one used for the unsnappening by Professor Hulk. Tony's armor is nanotech, and so can mold to different specifications as needed. That's how he was able to create the receptacles for the stones on his hand - it was on-demand at that moment.

Comment: @vynsane It's not covered, but it's likely the first gauntlet wasn't really "purpose built" either. Perhaps "purposed programmed" would be a better description, and it was loaded as instructions to nanites on what form to take. When he needed the same capability in the suit of armor he was currently wearing, he just fired up the relevant functions in that program and fed it to a different set of nanites - his suit.